# Why doesn't anything happen after copying Shiny App files to Shiny Server?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have encountered problems when trying to upload Shiny apps onto a Shiny Server that is already up and running.
I copied a folder containing the ui.R and server.R files on to the server.
When I try to open the app in the browser by accessing webpage /servername/myUser/folderName, nothing happens. I remain on the front page.
I have tried with several different small example programs, that all run in R when I try.
I also tried to gather my ui.R and server.R to one file "app.R", but the problem persists.
There is another Shiny App on the server, and that one works fine by accessing /servername/otherUser/folderName, so I am not sure what the problem is.
It is the first time I am trying this so it might be something simple that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the server I was using hadn't installed the packages necessary to run the App.